# 301 redirect not working correctly with php in old URL

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

This url

```
Redirect 301 /productdetail.php?pId=11390&base=1 http://domain.com/new-magento-url.html
```

This works

```
Redirect 301 /supertest http://domain.com/new-magento-url.html
```

I can see it is the .php but how do I except for that?

Comment: Looks like you need proper escaping for ? and .

The regex actually means product.phppId or product.phId, not product.php?Id (the ? makes the last p optional).

Try \? and \. instead of ? and .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pId=11390&base=1
RewriteRule productdetail.php http://example.com/new-magento-url.html? [R=301,L]
```

That should match the query string you want and perform the redirect. Place it above the last Magento rewriterule for index.php